# "Use samples" "Upload samples" for a button?

Tags: buttons, names, files, upload

**It's a web app that allows you to translate text files you upload.**

If you don't have any files to upload but want to test the app we allow you to use some samples.

They aren't added to the project by default because few users need them. Most people upload their own files.

**So, the upload page has 2 buttons:**

**upload files** and **use samples**.

Once the user clicks the button - 3 sample files will appear. Once the user clicks Upload files he/she can choose files from the machine.

**Question: how to better name the "use samples" button?**

Answer (score 1):

If the samples are used for demonstration purposes, you could use the label Demo in the button, which is fairly prevalent for software applications.

I used 'or' between the buttons to indicate a choice, but I haven't seen the rest of your UI.

I chose the word **Select** for the second version, because it sounds like there's another step in which they pick a sample.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRBpwc.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It may be unnecessary to have that button in the first place. The only meaningful choices are "use my data" or "use sample data", and you can tell which one of those to do without needing to ask the user about it:

- Before the user uploads any files of their own, just automatically show the sample data (with an indicator that it's an example, and a link to the upload area.)
- After the user has uploaded some of their own data, the samples aren't necessary any more, so remove them.

Comment: the problem is there are 2 more buttons I failed to mention - set up integration and invite users(if you don't have access to the needed files and just set up the app for somebody else)

Comment: @Oksi Those seem totally unrelated, I wouldn't change my answer based on the existence of those buttons.